# Checking if the address is valid in Linux kernel (other than NULL check)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

For example I have allocated a memory for 4096 bytes using `vmalloc`, I have a counter which keeps track of the allocated memory being written with in interrupt context something like:

```
if (data_to_read >= 4) {
  readdata();
  data_to_read -= 4;
} else if (data_to_read < 4) {
  memcpy();
}
```

Somehow the counter got corrupt and updates the value to read for remaining bytes to be 1 (data_to_read) and the kernel tries to write the memory and crashes. In this case is there a way to check before the memcpy if the address passed is valid or not?

Comment: Nothing is understandable from the provided excerpts.

Comment: Please provide a larger code sample.  There are many things it could be, but no way for us to take a guess with just those few lines.

Comment: Presumably, some code outside the interrupt context is increasing the value of `data_to_read`. What mechanism do you use to avoid race conditions (perhaps a spin-lock)?

Comment: @IanAbbott, I too thought that and tried using the spin_lock but even after the spin_lock is added the problem persisted which leads me to think the issue with either the DDR, MMU or the Kernel itself. I have raised a concern there so would get some clarity on that.